# jcifs.smb.SmbException: The parameter is incorrect

Tags: jcifs

I am trying to access a printer (Barcode Sticker Printer which is connected to Windows and shared to the network) via a Java program in Unix. 
I am able to use the smb client via the Unix script and print the sticker and trying to do the same with Java. 
I am able to get the access to the Machine and it displays the services available which displays the printer detail as well. 
When i try to use write via the stream i am getting the error jcifs.smb.SmbException: The parameter is incorrect. 
Didnt get much information from the web on this issue. code snippet as below

```
SmbFile smbFile; 
smbFile = new SmbFile(path); 
System.out.println("Type == "+smbFile.getType()); 
SmbFileOutputStream smbfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(smbFile); smbfos.write(getContent().getBytes());
```

SmbFileOutputStream smbfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(smbFile); this line Throws the error. 
The stacktrace is as below

```
jcifs.smb.SmbException: The parameter is incorrect. at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.checkStatus(SmbTransport.java:563) at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:663) at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:238) at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.send(SmbTree.java:119) at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.send(SmbFile.java:775) at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open0(SmbFile.java:992) at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open(SmbFile.java:1009) at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:142) at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:97) at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:67) at PrintJavaAPItest.printViaSimba(PrintJavaAPItest.java:127) at PrintJavaAPItest.main(PrintJavaAPItest.java:192)
```

Appreciate any input on this. Regards Vinod